# Overlay a map below a 3D scatter plot

Tags: matlab, dictionary, scatter3d

I made a figure that plots a 3D scatter of a flight path. Currently, since it's just a XYZ grid, I can't actually visualize where it was placed. Is there a way I can place a map of California and surrounding oceans (which is where the flight took place) on the X plane (or just right below) the scatter so I can see where the flight took place?

```
x = SARP2014(:,6); % longitude vector
y = SARP2014(:,5); % latitude vector
z = SARP2014(:,4); % Pressure Altitude vector

%% Figure
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]) % Open window fullsize
scatter3(x,y,z,100,z, 'fill') % Make filled 3D scatter plot
colorbar; % Add a colorbar
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have Matlab write this out in KML format to display in Google Earth.

Here's some documentation on plotting points of a path in KML: [link](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#paths)